# Putting queries in a php include

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I have a php include that houses some queries and want to be able to call them when needed by just running a function. When running the function I am not getting the query returned. Not sure if I need to use a return(); in the include or not.

```
<?php
// include file with queries
function displayQueryOne(){
$q = "SELECT * FROM culturegrams.new_to WHERE edition = '$url' ORDER BY placement ASC";     
$results= mysql_query($q) or die('could not run Query '.mysql_error());
return($results);

}
?>


<?php
//PAGE # 2 page to display query results
require('queryfile.php');

//running function from the include file
$results = displayQueryOne()

//running indpendent php while loop that will generate hmtl



    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){

?>

    <div class="top_menu"><p class="menu_text"><?php echo $r['title'];?></p></div>
    <div class="mid_menu">      
        <p class="explore_text">
            <?php echo $r['text'];?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to make it return like so

```
function displayQueryOne(){
  $q = "SELECT * FROM culturegrams.new_to WHERE edition = '$url' ORDER BY placement ASC";     
  $results= mysql_query($q) or die('could not run Query '.mysql_error());
  return $results;
}
```

Then you need to call it like this

```
$results = displayQueryOne();
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I was just providing an answer to his question which was how to return from a function. I personally use mysqli myself.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I've adjusted my code above and I am still  not getting displaying of my content. I had it working earlier minus it being inside a function.

Comment: Are you using multiple databases? In that case you will also need to pass the reference.

Comment: Nope for this query its very simple just one.

Comment: Did you get any type of error? Try doing a var_dump($results); and see what it's printing?

Comment: I went with this //include page function displayQueryOne($id){query here...  return $results;   //inside the php page $results = displayQueryOne($id); //the id is assigned at the top of the page somewhere so it's unique on every page. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you function will return an array since that is the one you are really up to.

```
function displayQueryOne(){

$q = "SELECT * FROM culturegrams.new_to WHERE edition = '$url' ORDER BY placement ASC";     
$query = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
     if($query)
     {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
             $array[] = $row;
        }
        return $array;
     }else{ return 'Nothing';}
}
```